# Flie name with space in names does no get downloaded

Tags: php

I am sending  a link in email to download a file , problem is if the
 file name contains spaces in filename  it does not get down loaded.

**example working:**

> Resume: http://www.procreations.in/resumes/14278870091CSS.docx

**Not working:**

> http://www.procreations.in/resumes/14278880294Blog link.docx

```
How to solve Space files download problem ?
```

Comment: Replace the space with +: `str_replace(" ","+",$string);`

Comment: let me try and check

Comment: Thanks Your idea worked for me with small change:     str_replace(" ","%20",$string);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.procreations.in/resumes/14278880294Blog%20link.docx
will work.

Replace space for %20